# Broken navigation in IE

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

I am currently designing a new website template.
I got the idea to use a click navigation menu just to have a cool feature(it has a fall back for if javascript is disabled).

I got the menu from [Toddmotto.com](http://toddmotto.com/flawless-clickable-drop-down-navigation/).
It worked flawlessly in every browser I checked my site in (Opera, Chrome, FF, Safari), then I tried IE and it does not look nearly the same.

The site I am designing my template on is [here](http://synesterpiercing.webs.com/index.htm).

Any help as to why it is broken is appreciated.

EDIT: Fixed by declaring doctype and adding the provided meta tag but now there appears to be a gap in my wrapper div that i do not have in my css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> HTML1200: webs.com is on the Internet Explorer Compatibility View List ('C:\Users\Kolink\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IECompatData\iecompatdata.xml').
>   index.htm
>
> HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. The shortest valid doctype is "`<!DOCTYPE html>`".
>   index.htm, line 1 character 1

The first problem can be fixed by adding this to your `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

The second can be fixed by adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the start of your page. Not having a doctype is something from last milennium...

Comment: hmmm for some reason my header_wrapper div now has padding at the bottom even though its not in my CSS.

Comment: What's the difference in the meta tag you provided and this one?

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />

Comment: Mine will tell IE that the site is actually done right. Yours is basically saying "it works in IE9 and I can't be arsed to test it in anything else"